# A new image for a widget does not appear

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have 2 classes, first one is Game where's located the main window and its settings, the second one is Piece that have some parameters to establish a Button with an image on its surface using Pillow. From the main class Game I planned call the other class to create objects on this window(root). Everything works fine(1st pic) untill I call my setter from any of these classes to change the image of the Button(Piece), it doesn't appear though the path to the new file is absolutely correct and the button becomes enabled if I'm not wrong and it's not clickable (2nd pic)
How can I resolve the problem, cos I need this possibility to change pictures on the button for my tic-toe game?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk



class Game:

    ICON = "./rsc/logo.ico"
    KREST_IMAGE = "./rsc/krest.png"
    DEFAULT_IMAGE = "./rsc/1.png"

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Tic-tac-toe")
        self.root.iconbitmap(Game.ICON)
        self.root.resizable(False,False)
        self.root.geometry("300x300+500+500") 
        
        self.c = Piece() 

        self.root.mainloop()
        

    
class Piece:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = Game.DEFAULT_IMAGE
        self.piece = Button(image = self._img)
        self.img = Game.KREST_IMAGE 
# for ex. calling again the setter. Writing direct path instead of Game.KREST_IMAGE doesn't help.
        self.piece.pack()

    @property
    def img(self):
        return self._img
    @img.setter
    def img(self, path):
        self.temp = Image.open(path)
        self.temp = self.temp.resize((20,20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.temp = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.temp)
        self._img = self.temp
```

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f2Xn.png)

Comment: maybe you forgot to update button after you changed `self.img` to KREST, add `self.piece = Button(image = self._img)`

Comment: Exactly! I just noticed my nuisance before your answer and now It works as it musts. Thanks anyway!